# Is there a fetchCount for @Query?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

For fetching data, there's a `fetchCount()` available:

```
let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Employee>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.salary > 100_000 })
let count = (try? modelContext.fetchCount(descriptor)) ?? 0
```

Is there a way to use something similar for the `@Query` property wrapper? This is the current alternative, but it might be loading more than it has to:

```
@Query(filter: #Predicate<Employee> { $0. salary > 100_000 }) var employees
```

inside the view:

```
if !employees.isEmpty {
    // show something
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with **"it might be loading more than it has to"**? Do you need the employees array or just the count?

Comment: Why not use the first code snippet in onAppear and assign the result to a @State property?

Comment: @Timmy I just want the count. The reason I said "might" is because afaik it's trying to be smart about what to load. If I only access the count, maybe it's already not loading everthing

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that wouldn't update the data if it changes, right?

Comment: No there isn’t, you can use a computed property so it refreshes when the view refreshes

Comment: That's right, then you need a Query if you want it automatically refreshed.